# adb shell command - cd: No such file or directory

Tags: android, linux, shell

I use an android 4.0 system on my device, when I use adb shell log in and want to go to the /cache directory with using cd cache, but it just show

> /system/bin/sh: cd: /cache - No such file or directory

Why? I really see the cache use ls command, it shows like

> lrwxrwxrwx root     root             2012-03-12 10:22 cache -> /data/cache"

Cd to other directory is ok. Has anybody can help me?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
cd /cache
```

do

```
cd /data/cache
```

or

If you type `ls` and you see cache, you should type `cd cache` because `cd /cache` is a directory just under the root `/`

Answer (score 0):

`/cache` is a symbolic link to a non-existent directory.  `cd /cache` is the same as `cd /data/cache`.  if `/data/cache` does not exist (which looks to be your problem) you'd get the "No such..." error.

Additionally, if you do `ls -L /cache` you'd get the same "No such..." error; that's because the `-L` option tries to list the target of the link (which does not exist, in this case) instead of the link.

Finally:

```
ln -s  this_directory_almost_certainly_does_not_exist   not_sure_if_this_exists
test -f not_sure_if_this_exists || echo 'Nope, it does not exist'
```